# Is it possible to upload a single design file in ZIP to BIM360 Docs?

Tags: autodesk-data-management

IFC files can be quite large (10Mb++). ZIP of IFC is reducing the file’s size 10x+. Such reduction in size improves dramatically performance of upload / download operations from / to BIM360 / A360 projects. BIM360 Docs allows to upload ZIP of related files. However, when I manually trying to upload ZIP of a single IFC file (also tried with single DWG in ZIP), the upload process fails with “Extract failed” message. Is extract of single files from ZIP compressed archive supported by BIM360 Docs?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not within the bounds of discussion as described in the help center.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried with a DWF compressed as a .ZIP. It **DOESN'T** work for files on BIM 360 Docs (uploaded via API and translated via `POST job`), but it does work for Buckets (2-legged).